# how to access to javaBean attribus from javaScript functions?

Tags: java, javascript

Is it possible to get java object attributes from javascript function.

Example by using EL language  :

```
function jsFunction(){
    var name = #{myBean.name};
}
```

Comment: javaScript is client side, so i think this won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly -- no.

You'll need to pass java bean to client (most often done using JSON) and get modified bean back from client via HTTP request (`GET` or, preferrably, `POST`). This is what AJAX for (though AJAX can be used with any server-side execution environment, JVM or not).

Comment: ah so the only way is to pass through servlets! hummm thak you

Comment: @berber5 servlets or jsps (actually, jsps are compiled to servlets before execution, so these two options are technically equivalent). Although, if you stick to proper MVC, as you should do, dynamic content for AJAX interaction must be served to client and back by servlets, definitely.

Comment: I have used the first option (servlets)
but with jsps I known't how it works

Comment: @berber5 I would recommend you to check exhaustive J2EE 1.4 tutorial at Oracle site: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/ (there are newer versions but they are about more trendy parts of J2EE stack,  servlets and JSPs are covered in 1.4 most exhaustively);

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax libraries like [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html), in this way you can access server side Java objects from your JavaScript code.

[Here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/scripting-dwr.html) you can find simple examples how to do basic remoting

Answer (score 1):

If you use a modern JSF framework like Primefaces, you can use built-in command components such as `<p:remoteCommand>`.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

e.g.

```
<h:form>    
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="msgs" actionListener="#{remoteCommandView.execute}" />     
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />    
<p:commandButton type="button" onclick="rc()" value="Execute" icon="ui-icon-refresh" />
</h:form>
```

... where `rc()` is the javascript method name that you use to access the `remoteCommandView` bean method `execute`.

e.g.

```
<div onclick="rc()">Clicking Here Calls remoteCommandView.execute</div>
```

or

```
<script>
function something(){ 
rc(); 
}
</script>
```